# Intro to Differential Equations Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $y(t)= C_1 e^{2t} + C_1 e^{-2t}$ is a solution to the differential equation $y'' - 4y = 0$. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

This was the first part of the problem which I understood and completed fine. All I had to do here was substitute in the given solution to ensure that it equaled zero.

The second part is where I don't even know where to begin: Using the results of this, solve the initial value problem where $y(0)= 2$ and $y'(0)=0$.
The answer-key for this problem simply said the correct answer to this was: $y= e^{2t}+e^{-2t}=2\cosh 2t$

I'm not even sure of the correct steps to get to this answer. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a way to format your equations neatly: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Comment: BTW: I believe your equation should be $y(t)=C_1e^{2t}+C_2e^{-2t}$. You have $C_1$ in both terms.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the values and plug them in:
$$\begin{cases}y=c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t}\\y'=2c_1e^{2t}-2c_2e^{-2t}\\y''=4c_1e^{2t}+4c_2e^{-2t}\end{cases}\\y''-4y=4c_1e^{2t}+4c_2e^{-2t}-4(c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t})=0$$

Second part you're given initial conditions:
$$y(0)=2=c_1e^{2(0)}+c_2e^{-2(0)}=c_1+c_2\\y'(0)=0=2c_1e^{2(0)}-2c_2e^{-2(0)}=2c_1-2c_2$$

So you get:

$$c_1=2-c_2\\c_1=c_2$$

And using algebra, you get that $c_2=c_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply substitute $t-0$ into the expression for $y(t)$ to get:$$0=C_1e^0+C_2e^0=C_1+C_2\tag{1}$$then differentiate $y(t)$ to get:$$y'(t)=2C_1e^{2t}-2C_2e^{-2t}$$and again substitute $t=0$ into this to get:$$0=2C_1-2C_2\tag{2}$$Now you have two equations with two unknowns which you can solve to find $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Answer (score 0):

the first part is correct(can be solved by using the characteristic polynomial), to find the constants, you must derive the initial equation and plug in the data(i.e. putting 0 in and so that y(0)=2, and like so in y'(0)=0), this will give you 2 equations with 2 variables. so you can easily find the constants. As for the 2 cosh 2t, this seems to be a mistake, as you have a homogeneous ODE, and so the solution will be the sum of constants* exp(roots of the characteristic polynomial).